# Give priority to the Y value of a vector

Tags: vector, processing

When limiting a vector `myVector.limit(10);` could you give "priority" to the Y value? IE subtract from the X on the vector but do not touch the Y?
I was thinking of using the following pseudo code

```java
if(myVector.mag()>=10)
{
myVector.x--;
}
```

Is that a "good" idea or is there a better way of approaching this problem?

EDIT:

What I am doing is trying to limit the speed of a car when it goes uphill. By limiting the X I hope to prevent it from just "jumping" up the hills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't tell you whether this is a good idea, because it really depends on what you're trying to do.

I will say that your approach won't handle the case where you want to limit your `PVector` to something that's smaller than the `y` value.

But sure, nothing is stopping you from treating the `x` and `y` values separately. You might consider using the `map()` or `constrain()` functions.

```
//limits your `y` value to be between 0 and 10
myVector.y = constrain(myVector.y, 0, 10);
```

Another hint would be to look at [the source code](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PVector.java) behind the `PVector#limit()` function, which is pretty simple:

```
 public PVector limit(float max) {
    if (magSq() > max*max) {
      normalize();
      mult(max);
    }
    return this;
  }
```

All this is doing is making the magnitude of the `PVector` equal whatever you pass into the `limit()` function. You could do something similar to just the `y` value. Maybe use division to figure out what `y` value would give you the target magnitude given the `x` value?

But like I said, what you do really depends on what your goal here is.

**Edit:** You might also consider changing how you're storing your movement. Instead of storing an X speed and a Y speed, store an angle and a velocity.

In other words, keep track of the direction you're heading, and how fast you're going. Then you can use `cos()` and `sin()` to figure out the X speed and Y speed. Then you just need to limit the overall speed instead of limiting the Y speed separately.

Comment: I think that I learn more from what you tell me about how I need to fix up/improve my question asking then by reading the guidelines for SO. Thanks again Mr. Workman! I am editing my question to improve it for the sake of the community.

Comment: @ChristopherPeart Haha, no problem. Thanks for taking the time to improve your question. I've also edited my answer to include another approach you might consider.

Comment: I think that you are for sure one of the reasons SO keeps me coming back. Sadly most questions I cannot answer but always working to give back!

Comment: @ChristopherPeart Asking good questions is a form of giving back. Without interesting questions we wouldn't have anything to do here!

Comment: @ChristopherPeart You too!